# Jsf SelectItem Converter

Tags: jsf

JSF use converter when translating value between backing bean and frontend jsf page.Jsf also support custom converters.My question is when i want to use a list of my custom object as selectitems  for a face component,how can i convert this object list to selectitems.I am currently doing this usig a metod which is return a List ,but there should be a way doing this with coverters.

I am using jsf 1.2 myfaces

Comment: Sorry i will set correct answers.